# Scala regex parser for key:value pairs

Tags: regex, scala, parsing, configuration

I'm new to Scala and need a parser to create tuples from a config statement of form:

```
key1: value; key2: "String Values can include;:"; key3: "".....
```

Also, how do I run the parser (am finding the documentation examples very short....)

i.e, given the config string - how do extract the list of tuples?

thanks

Comment: If you make the config in JSON or XML, there will be plenty of libraries you could use here

Comment: Thanks Ben,  but it's not my configuration file,  I want to convert it to json

Answer (score 4):

I will assume that you have a pair of  where value is string.

You can do something like this:

```
val string = "key1: \"value\"; key2: \"String Values can include;:\"; key3: \"\""
val pattern = """(\w*?):\s*(\".*?\")""".r
pattern.findAllIn(string).matchData foreach {
   m => println(m.group(1) + m.group(2))
}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/fN0lK8/2)**

[image]

On the other hand, if your values are objects, then I think you should find another way to do it instead of regex.

Comment: You can use `p.findAllMatchIn` and match on `pattern(k, v)` for the extraction.

Comment: This resulted in:     key1: "value"; key2: "String Values can include;"; key3: " instead of key1:"value"; key2:"String Values can include;:";key3:""  i.e. the quoted ":" disappeared and the last empty string lost its closing quotes -